# Running multiple versions of Internet Explorer on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7

I really need to start testing my code on multiple versions of Internet Explorer. Does anyone know how to do it? I'm on a Dell XPS 1530 laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its a bit overkill but the only way I know is to set up a virtual box with windows in it and install a different one that installation. Or you could try compatibility view

Comment: I asked this question a long time ago, but I figured I'd give an update since this page still gets hits from time to time. I ended up using [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html) to build a few virtual machine with various versions of IE as well as Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera (just to be thorough). Works like a charm, and it's free! :) Yes, it takes a bit of time, but I found too many quirks with the IE Developer Tools to want to actually rely solely on them.

Answer (score 4):

[Reliable Cross-Browser Testing, Part 1: Internet Explorer](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/02/reliable-cross-browser-testing-part-1-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using Microsoft Virtual PC to run several virtual machines with different IE versions. Microsoft even offers the images:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575